# RegionPlot with four parameters

Tags: plotting, regions, parametric-functions, inequalities

I will try to illustrate my question with an example:

Let us define the `RegionPlot` for `b` and `y` as

```
ybregion=RegionPlot[Sin[b]^2 + Sinh [y] <= 1, {y, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

for `0 <= b <= 1` and `0 <= y <= 1`. Moreover, we have `0 <= a <= 1` and `0 <= x <= by^2`. Notice that the interval for `x` depends on `b` and `y` satisfying e.g. `Sin[b]^2 + Sinh [y] <= 1`. Let us define, for example, the function

```
f = a + (b x)/y
```

I would like to make a plot such that we can see the cases `f=0,1,2`, for example, in terms of `a` and `b` as an `(a,b,f)` plot. My problem is to handle with the condition `Sin[b]^2 + Sinh [y] <= 1` and with the four variables of `f`. In my original problem `a, b, f` are physical parameters so a useful plot should be one without `x, y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me offer some possible plots.

First regard, that the x-y area is very limited.

```
RegionPlot3D[
   0 <= x <= b y^2 && Sin[b]^2 + Sinh[y] <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 
   0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= x <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100]

{xmax, parxmax} = 
  NMaximize[{x, 
  0 <= x <= b y^2 && Sin[b]^2 + Sinh[y] <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 
0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, {y, 0, 1/2}, b}]

{ymax, parymax} = 
  NMaximize[{y, 
     0 <= x <= b y^2 && Sin[b]^2 + Sinh[y] <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 
  0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, {y, 0, 1/2}, b}]
```

**Edit** 
Corrected typos, got changed pictures.

See f = 1 depending an a,b,x,y

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[a + (b x)/y, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {x, 0, xmax}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{a, b, x}, 0 <= x <= b y^2 && Sin[b]^2 + Sinh[y] <= 1], 
 Contours -> {0, 1, 2, 3}, ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Cyan}, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, Mesh -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "x"}], {{y, .4}, 0, ymax}]
```

[image]

Or a plot of f[a,b] and x,y as parameters.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot3D[{1, a + (b x)/y}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{a, b, f}, 0 <= x <= b y^2 && Sin[b]^2 + Sinh[y] <= 1], 
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "f"}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
 ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.2], 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Opacity[.2]}, Blue}, Mesh -> False], {{x, .1}, 
 0, xmax}, {{y, .4}, 0, ymax}]
```

[image]